# Updating django pluggable apps after modification

Tags: django

I'm using django-basic-apps' blog app, but I have a few modification to it: added a ManyToManyField and a URLField.

Is it possible to maintain my modifications while keeping up-to-date with the most recent release of the apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just fork the project on GitHub. You can then regularly merge from the parent project, while keeping your modifications.

You can do this via your own git repo as well, if you don't want to make your modifications public, but GitHub is easier as it has all this set up for you already.

Answer (score 0):

It might be best to extend the existing models from django-basics-apps, have a look at:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

```
# custom_blog/models.py
from blog.models import Post


class CustomPost(Post):
    new_field_one = ManyToManyField
    new_field_two = URLField
```